# Pjsip video call

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pjsip

I am looking for video call for my door intercom system. I followed the famous "pjproject" for audio calls. It is also mentioned that pjsip is video API supportable. I tried to make video call but couldn't figure out how to proceed with that. I tried to initiate video call in same "sample" file, that is used for audio call.

First I tried to switch auto transmission and auto start video on call but that didn't work. Then I tried to get the count and info of video device using commands `vid_dev_count` and `vid_dev_get_info` both didn't work.

> ERROR AttributeError: Lib instance has no attribute 'vid_dev_count'

and same for other. Even I tried to access class "VideoDeviceInfo":

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoDeviceInfo'

First of all whether pjsip API is supportable for Raspberry Pi or not? I read it is mostly supported on PC not portable devices(for video).

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions for building PJSIP with video support like [here](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf), on the section video support? Because there is a big difference between the PJSIP build with and without video support. Further more i can't help you without any sourcecode.

Comment: So I have to make a new start?

Comment: yes, you have to compile it again. If that was your question.